# link for adding something to the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I have a link that would add something to the session hash? For example if I had a link, can it do this when clicked:

```
session[:items] << item
```

I'll probably have to have the link trigger a JS file for that action, so I can update the session when the user clicks the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I did, in case someone else runs across, I executed this line in my controller, for example this would be if we added something to our params.

```
session[:items] << Item.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: This is really the only way to do it.